# jQuery slide scrolling overlapping issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlapping

I'm designing an EPK for my band and I'm having some problems. On my screen, the proportions are great in every browser. But on my bassists computer, elements are overlapping. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why?

Here's the site:
http://www.indefinitedyad.com/epk.html

and here's a jsFiddle with the code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mkk9F/

Here's how it's turning up on her screen:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v410/justice4all_quiet/Screenshot2012-07-29at22149PM.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What browser is used in the picture?

Comment: There's a lot of strange coding going on in here. E.G On your #menu element you're trying to float it and position it absolutely. I'd recommend taking a step back starting again one element at a time. You should test in all popular browsers as you go along building the site to make sure it's as cross-browser compatible as it can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell this is actually a CSS issue and it is because your .content width is set to 90%. If you resize your browser or have a higher resolution monitor it looks fine. You need to set your content division to a defined width if you want a set size (1080px works nice on my browser), or alternatively look into a grid system such as the 1140px grid which can be found [here](http://cssgrid.net/) which works for mobile and screen resizing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your `<ul id="menu">` has `position: absolute;`. This makes the button stick to the frame, and not scale with the window. However, your `<div class="container">` does not do this. Thus your div containing the picture etc. will scale as you make the window smaller/bigger. But the buttons will not.

This issue is extremely simple to reproduce. **Make your browserwindow smaller**. This is a matter of fixing your html setup.